# Youtube, the site itself freezing for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, youtube

i've been plagued by a problem that seem to started since Youtube's last
layout change this year.

I have for months put up and tried to ignore the freezing that happens
everytime I open a link within youtube such as an channel, an video, the homepage, etc.

I'm using Chrome version 31.0.1650.63 and I have already tested youtube without any
extensions, cookies, cache, etc but it still affects me to this day and maybe some
of you out there.

I searched every where for the solution and couldn't find any anywhere.
I did a bit of digging and testing to see what is the root of the problem and
while i'm no expertise on code or Java...I did found something.

Every time I reload a page on youtube, with it finishing loading up...this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtJId.png

See that?
The purple-colored rendering, that's the cause of the lag every time I load
up something on youtube!

I notice that it repeats the same thing over and over again for like 5-15 or so
seconds before it starts loading up the thumbnails of the videos.

If you want a closer inspection of the code, here's the raw data from the timeline (that you can load up in chrome's dev timeline window):
[Youtube Lag JSON Timeline file](http://up.ht/1iIR38a)

I don't what to do with this problem and I believe it affects
me in Firefox as well but to an lesser extent then chrome.

Do any of you guys know how to resolve this problem?
Honestly I doubt that the youtube devs will fix this problem since they're the ones who caused it in the first place. (Like not being able to subscribe to some people when i'm not even at my sub limit.)

I'm sorry if you don't want to help but I don't know who else to look to besides
the experts that y'all are when it comes to web coding. If anything, I believe a userscript or something similar could help with this but how...I don't know.

I'm new to this and I apologize if the question i'm asking isn't suited for this site.
Still, thanks for reading and if you can...please reply.

That is all and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was fiddling around and looking at the source code
with chromes timeline devtools and well...

I found a temporary solution to the problem which seems to have
fixed and ended the freezing on youtube! yay~

But some things don't work with this solution and i'm at
a fault with this issue after some hours trying to figure out
how to stop the problem.

Anyways I used adblock, an extension that I have on Google Chrome, to deal
with this issue and was able to get everything fixed and working!

What I did was, in the custom filters section (check options in your
adblock extension, you should have it.) and added the following then did
some testing to see if it fixed the problem which it did!

Here are the filters I used to fix it!

```
||s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-pageframe-*
*www-pageframe-*.js
```

^^^
Yeah, that's the temporary solution as it fixes the problems but it causes the following...

> 1. You can't open the menu which contains links to your playlists, user settings, channel, etc when you click your username or profile
>      picture on top right of youtube.
> 2. The "..." mini-menu that you usually find on the right of a video section (to hide, subscribe, etc.) doesn't appear anymore.
> 3. Youtube's quick menu button doesn't work, however the menu is still open but you won't be able to close it. That or it's close and you
>      won't be able to open it...I guess.

Those are the problems I found with this temporarily solution to the freezing problem.

Yeah...but I hope this helps anyone who's having this problem somewhat well.
But it would be nice if someone has an better solution then mine hehe!

Thanks for reading and if you have a better solution, don't feel afraid to
tell! ^_^

I'll be awaiting other answers, for now...I hope this helps y'all well
in some ways hehe! =D

Comment: This may not be a good question for StackOverflow but I wonder why this issue isn't more prevalent, or fixed until now. The pageframe JS still freezes the site for 10 seconds on load. Blocking it renders the sidebar unusable so that isn't a permanent solution either...

Answer (score 1):

This certainly isn't javascript, but substituting the normal EasyList in ABP for EasyList without element hiding will fix the issue. There are downsides to this as well but for now seems to be the better solution.